# Free cloud syncing service for phone camera that also mirrors the device's directory structure

Tags: gratis, cloud-service, cloud-storage

I was a [SugarSync](https://www.sugarsync.com/) user and really love the way they sync my camera roll into album folder, maintaining the folder structure in my phone. Since they took down the free option, I want to move to another service, such as [Bitcasa](https://www.bitcasa.com/) or [Copy](https://www.copy.com/home/). The downside is these sync the camera roll into one big folder.

Is there any sync service like Sugarsync that sorts my camera roll into album folders?
I have tried Bitcasa, Copy, Dropbox, Skydrive. All of them use one big folder.